# Bone cause model to move when un-wanted

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have a model that I'm working on and for some reason the bone moves the breast area even though it's weight is set to zero. Here's an image to show what I'm talking about.

[image]

Like shown, There's no weight assigned to it at all but it somehow moves the model still.

Here's the model's  topology.

[image]

and here's the model with the bone at rest pose

[image]

edit: same goes to the top.

at rest pose. Also weight is assigned to zero.

[image]

and when moving the bone

[image]

To clarify. As far as I checked. No other bone is related with this issue. None of them have any weights assigned to the part of model I'm having issue with. Though I will double check to be sure.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Is there a way I give the file to you only. I don't feel like just placing it on the public.

Comment: Only keep the mesh and armature, not the rest  ;)

Comment: The winky face xD anyways here's the file with da anti piracy!!
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=ndWNYkDN" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ndWNYkDN/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the breast vertices are assigned to the vertex groups called Right Breast and Left Breast, so they are controlled by the bones that have the same name

Comment: Even without checking your file, your screenshots show that the breast has colors different than dark blue (=0), so the weight is not 0. It may not be assigned to that spine bone, but the breast bones are moved by the spine, so the breast bones move the breasts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Each bone has its own weight paint but is going to affect other bones if they are connected together(*). So the breast should be red. But the mid-torso should gradually turn blue as the breast weight has already been assigned with the breast bone

the point where it should have the most bend which in this case is the mid-torso. I will paint it with a higher-weight paint. But as it reaches the breast area. It should decrease. The same goes for the upper torso. The top area is where it should have the heavier-weight paint. But slowly decreases as the middle bone has its own weight assigned and you need to have an evenly distributed weight paint for the mesh to work properly

(red means that part will follow the bone 100%, and Blue means not follow)

All the bones have to be properly painted in order for the model to move correctly(*).

thirdly. As I said above. All bones have to be painted correctly in order for the mesh to work correctly(*). This is due to the fact that each bone that's linked to the main bone that you're moving will also move together(Or the fact that the mesh is one piece). causing some of it to distort. You have to check each bone and paint them correspondingly so it works right.

simplified version: paint each part of the body's bone from bottom to top or top to bottom. Paint each bone with its own weight. Same for the next bone. Paint the part where you think will bend the most with the heavier weights. and decrease gradually. And make sure each bone after weight painting has a smooth gradient of the paint

or during painting, you can also check if it's smooth so you don't have to go back and check it later on.

If anything that I pointed out is wrong please let me know I will change it as quickly as possible :D I'll continue to change if I find anything wrong also. Or if I discover it during this weight painting nightmare.

[* meaning I'm not sure about the effect of weight distribution is with bone or mesh]

(Also if want images I can upload but I got a bit lazy:l)